# Cloth, Corn and Gold: James Stuart Mill example

Tags: international-trade, balance-of-trade, classical-economics

I don't quite get James Stuart Mill's example of cloth, corn and gold in "Elements of Political Economy".

He supposes that 20 yards of cloth takes the same amount of effort to make as 4 quarters of corn in England, but in Poland the effort to make 4 quarters of corn is the same as that to make 10 yards of cloth.

Now, supposing that in the beginning corn costs 1 pound per quarter in both places, then the resulting cloth price will be 0.2 pounds in England and 0.4 pounds in Poland. Therefore, the Poles will buy cloth and gold will flow from Poland to England while cloth goes the other direction. This will continue until the price is the same in both places (0.27 pounds for a yard of cloth in both places).

However, in that case the corn price will drift out of balance.

Where is the equilibrium?

(This example is in Chapter III, Section XV)

Comment: What is the mechanism through which the price of cloth in the two countries will converge to something inbetween their levels prior to international trade? What happens to these economies that can justify/rationalize such change? Is it just arbitrage exploitation from the part of English cloth suppliers, and an attempt to retain clientele from the part of Polish cloth suppliers? Or it has something to do with productive factors changing sectors and/or countries?